# How to get exact hours and minutes from DbFunctions.DiffMinutes()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using this linq query,it works fine. only problem is it is returning hours in int i.e 10,9 etc but I want complete hours along with minutes i.e 10:28,9:45 etc

```
DayHours = (from ab in db.Attendances
               where ab.Employee == 63
                   && ab.InTime.Value.Year == 2015
                   && ab.InTime.Value.Month == i
               select new
               {
                   Day = ab.InTime.Value.Day,
                   Hours = DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(ab.InTime, ab.OutTime) / 60
               });
```

Comment: You're explicitly dividing the minutes by 60 to get the number of hours. If you want the total minutes, then don't do that?

Comment: but I want the total hours along with the remaining minutes e.g 10:57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/*...*/
      select new
      {
          Day = ab.InTime.Value.Day,
          Hours = DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(ab.InTime, ab.OutTime) / 60
          Minutes = DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(ab.InTime, ab.OutTime) % 60                   
       });
```

If you don't want it on this format, please specify exactly how do you want to store it (a `Timespan` variable? something else?)

Answer (score -1):

You Can get Exact Time from DB as

```
select round(
    Cast(
        DateDiff(
            MINUTE, 
            convert(varchar(5), '09:40:00.0000000', 108),
            convert(varchar(5), '18:12:00.0000000', 108)
        ) / 60 as float
    )
    + Cast(
        DateDiff(
            MINUTE, 
            convert(varchar(5), '09:40:00.0000000', 108),
            convert(varchar(5), '18:12:00.0000000', 108)
        ) % 60 as float
    ) / 60, 2
) as [Hour in office]
```